# Login using Authentication and Authorising

Tags: asp.net

I have two user "Admin" and "Creator", while login the page i have to authenticate it with database and to give full access to the admin and restrict few access to the creator.
can you please give me some idea regarding the above.

Comment: You are using Asp.Net Web Forms or Web Pages or MVC ?

Answer (score 0):

Use forms-authentication for this very purpose. Here is a tutorial for your particular scenario  http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20020906.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use Forms Authentication for your purpose.But if you are using it for the first time I suggest you do some reading firstly to understand how it works.Try [these tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security).For your purpose of Roles based authorization you will have to use Asp.Net Membership and Roles.I am assuming you are using Web Forms.It is going to be time consuming but it is worth referring.Hope it helps.

Comment: @RekhaShanmugam Then the link should give you a good starting point.It  will be a bit time consuming but trust me they are worth it.

Comment: @RekhaShanmugam Also start to accept and upvote answers if they help you.Thanks.